# Vb.net DataGridView repeating

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a problem in my DataGridView, please refer to the image below.

Image 1 shows that I've clicked "Add to Cart" on one of my products, the DataGridView shows the product.

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgfK2.png)

The problem is when I want to add another product, the list of products in the DataGridView repeats itself instead of adding another different product.
Image 2 shows what happens when I clicked "Add to Cart" on a new product.

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaE4Z.png)

```
 Private Sub btn_add_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_add.Click

    grd_cart.RowCount = grd_cart.RowCount + 1

    For i As Integer = 0 To grd_cart.RowCount - 1

        Dim product As String = grd_cart(0, i).Value
        Dim price As String = grd_cart(1, i).Value
        Dim quantity As String = grd_cart(2, i).Value
        Dim subtotal As String = grd_cart(3, i).Value

        grd_cart(0, i).Value = txt_product_id.Text
        grd_cart(1, i).Value = txt_price.Text
        grd_cart(2, i).Value = num_quantity.Value
        grd_cart(3, i).Value = grd_cart(1, 0).Value * grd_cart(2, 0).Value

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code loops through every row in the grid. Consider taking the loop out and just working with the new grid row.
More generally, it's probably better practice to bind the grid to a list of objects and work with that, leaving the databinding to take care of the presentation layer.

Comment: A simple trace of your code should reveal the problem. Put a breakpoint on the first line and trace what your code does. The variables `product`, `price`, `quantity` and `subtotal` are NEVER used. The second part of the code simply uses the SAME values that are in the text boxes and adds them to the grid. This is why you get the SAME values for each row. Simply tracing the code should reveal this.

Comment: As peter states… looping through the grid is unnecessary… simply, add a new row with the items from the text boxes. Use the variables `product`, `price`, `quantity`, etc from the TEXTBOXES (not the grid) then simply add a new row to the grid: `grd_cart.Rows.Add(product, price, quantity, subtotal)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cicle through the grid.
(Of course, this may depend on how you calculate the sub total.)

You just need to add a new Row to the grid, using the current values.

This can be a way to do it.

```
'Check whether the Price value is a number or not (to be safe)
'If can't be used as a number, return
Dim _Price As Long
If Long.TryParse(txt_price.Text, _Price) = False Then Return

'Calculate the subtotal value based on quantity and unit price
'I know not everyone calculates the sub total this way. In case, just add a comment.
Dim _subtotal As Long = CLng(num_quantity.Value) * _Price

'Add the new Row values
grd_cart.Rows.Add(New String() {txt_product_id.Text,
                                _Price.ToString,
                                num_quantity.Value.ToString,
                                _subtotal.ToString})
```

This is the result:

[image]

You might also present the values in Currency format:

```
'The output can also be formatted using the local Currency format
grd_cart.Rows.Add(New String() {txt_product_id.Text,
                                _Price.ToString("C"),
                                num_quantity.Value.ToString,
                                _subtotal.ToString("C")})
```

This is the result:

[image]